# Where do I put self built libraries on OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, libraries, gcc

I downloaded and built a C, g++ library that I want to use in a couple of other C projects.

What is the best/standard directory to put the library in on OS X Snow Leopard?

- `/opt/local/lib/`
- `/usr/local/lib/`
- any other?

And related: What is the standard library/include search path for g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib` is the standard place for these in almost any Unix-like OS.

MacPorts creates the `/opt` hierarchy so that it doesn't mess with what you've done manually in `/usr/local/`.

Fink creates the `/sw` hierarchy for similar reasons.

Homebrew I think still defaults to messing with `/usr/local` (a design decision I find distasteful), but I think it has a "prefix" option to make it use its own hierarchy instead.